# Attiny10 not triggering timer overflow interrupt while simulation (Atmel Studio 6)

Tags: avr, simulation, interrupts, attiny, atmel-studio

I have problems simulating the timer overflow in Atmel Studio 6. The code is for an Attiny10 and looks like below. As far as I know I set all the neccessary bits to enable the counter (which works in simulation) and the interrupt (which doesnt work in simulation).

I guess it's just a stupid mistake and I need a small hint so I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
;======================
;   device  attiny10
;======================
;.include   tn10def.inc
;            _____________
;           /1 °         6|
;       O--|PB0        PB3|--O RESET
;          |      t10     |
;       O--|GND        VCC|--O
;          |              |
;       O--|PB1        PB2|--O
;          |______________|

;======================
; defines
;======================
.def    temp    = r16

;======================
; reset / int. vecs
;======================
.org 0x0000
    rjmp    reset           ; Reset Handler
.org 0x0004
    rjmp    TIM0_OVF        ; Timer0 Overflow Handler
.org 0x000A

;======================
; reset / setup
;======================
reset:
    in      temp,   TCCR0B          ; turn timer on
    ori     temp,   (1<<CS00)
    out     TCCR0B, temp

    in      temp,   TIMSK0          ; turn overflow interrupt on
    ori     temp,   (1<<TOIE0)
    out     TIMSK0, temp

    ldi     0xff
    out     DDRB,   temp
    ldi     0x00
    out     PORTB,  temp

    ldi     temp,   0xff
    out     TCNT0H, temp
    ldi     temp,   250
    out     TCNT0L, temp

    ldi     temp,   0xff

    sei

;======================
; main loop
;======================
main:
    rjmp    main            ; while(1);

; overflow interrupt
;====================== 
TIM0_OVF:
    com     temp
    out     PORTB,  temp
    reti
```

**EDIT:** Solved: You cant step into/over an ISR. (Thx to Golaž)

Answer (score 2):

If you havent got a compiler error when trying to compile the exact code you posted, you have a bigger problem.

Your code is working fine (ignoring the fact you missed out the register names in your 3rd block under reset label). However I would make some changes:

```
;======================
;   device  attiny10
;======================
;.include   tn10def.inc
;            _____________
;           /1 °         6|
;       O--|PB0        PB3|--O RESET
;          |      t10     |
;       O--|GND        VCC|--O
;          |              |
;       O--|PB1        PB2|--O
;          |______________|

;======================
; defines
;======================
.def    temp    = r16

;======================
; reset / int. vecs
;======================
.org 0x0000
    rjmp    reset           ; Reset Handler
; Replace : .org 0x0004 with:
.org OVF0addr
    rjmp    TIM0_OVF        ; Timer0 Overflow Handler
; Replace: .org 0x000A with:
.org INT_VECTORS_SIZE ; End of vector table.

;======================
; reset / setup
;======================
reset:
    ; Initialize stack:
    ldi r16, HIGH(RAMEND)
    out SPH, r16
    ldi r16, LOW(RAMEND)
    out SPL, r16        

    in      temp,   TCCR0B          ; turn timer on
    ori     temp,   (1<<CS00)
    out     TCCR0B, temp

    in      temp,   TIMSK0          ; turn overflow interrupt on
    ori     temp,   (1<<TOIE0)
    out     TIMSK0, temp

    ; You forgot to specify the regsiter here:
    ldi     temp,   0xff
    out     DDRB,   temp
    ldi     temp,   0x00
    out     PORTB,  temp

    ldi     temp,   0xff
    out     TCNT0H, temp
    ldi     temp,   250
    out     TCNT0L, temp

    ldi     temp,   0xff

    sei

;======================
; main loop
;======================
main:
    rjmp    main            ; while(1);

; overflow interrupt
;====================== 
TIM0_OVF:
    com     temp
    out     PORTB,  temp
    reti
```

You can find the include files for devices and all their specifics (such as OVF0addr, INT_VECTORS_SIZE, RAMEND, ...) in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVRAssembler\Native\2.1.1117\avrassembler\include

I am not sure what your exact goal was here, when you've setted `TCNT0` registers you've only set its value for one (current) cycle, when the timer would reach its maximum value it will restart from 0.

What was your goal with `TIM0_OVF` ISR I am not sure.

Stack is needed for the MCU to know which address to return to after the call to subfunction or ISR have been executed.

Comment: Well the stack pointer is initialized to `RAMEND` by default (by the simulator) it doesnt change a thing with or without initializing it manually. I want to have a timebase. Setting `TCNT0` to that value make it overflowing in some tickes and i dont have to press `F11` `~60000` times to see it overflowing. I knot that the timer overflows from `MAX` to `0` but when that happens it sould execute the overflow `ISR` but it doesnt and thats the problem. Eventhough without initialized stackpointer the simulator should at least enter the `ISR` but it doesnt.

Comment: @user3097432 How did you come to the conclusion, that the ISR doesnt get fired? Did you put a brakepoint in there...?

Comment: @user3097432 You dont have to manually tap F11 60000 times, just put a brakepoint along side one of the instructions inside ISR and click run. Also, if nothing more manually setting stack pointer ensures better portabillity.

Comment: I know I dont have to tab `F11` 60000 times if I preset the timer register close to the `MAX` which I did. I can tell its not entering the ISR because I can step into (`F11`-key) and watch all the registers and the actual program counter position. I dont let the simulation run in free mode I let it run step by step so I let the program run op-code by op-code. And the code in the ISR, which is supposed to invert the value of `PORTB`, doesnt change `PORTB`.

Comment: @user3097432 Please do as described above.

Comment: Ok wow! Now it does enter the ISR in free running mode but why cant I see it entering step by step?

Comment: @user3097432 Because you cant step into/over an ISR.